# no puedo usar nlargest on my DataFrame de pandas en python

Tags: python, pandas

quiero obtener las columnas con los 5 Probas mas grandes, estoy intentando usar nlargest en este dataframe

```
print(df_predictions)
                   Names       Probas
0     ADRIAN FRANCISCOESPINOZAORTEGA  2.75548e-05
1               ALEJANDROLOPEZTINOCO  6.86191e-10
2          ALFREDO CAMARILLO GARCIA   1.16287e-06
3      ANGEL FRANCISCOANDRADENEGRETE  4.49354e-06
4                 ANGELBERMUDEZLOPEZ  9.85096e-10
..                               ...          ...
94             SAMUELHERNANDEZFLORES  2.52177e-06
95  SERGIO FERNANDORODRIGUEZAGUIÑAGA  1.00354e-05
96          SERGIOHERNANDEZGUTIERREZ  3.68218e-08
97     VICTOR HUGO VELAZQUEZ BRAVO    4.21608e-08
98                VICTORMORENOMORENO   4.4833e-06
```

cuando intento

```
most_likely = df_predictions.nlargest(5, 'Probas')
```

obtengo este error

```
typeError: Column 'Probas' has dtype object, cannot use method 'nlargest' with this dtype
```

espero que puedan decirme porque pasa y como hacerlo funcionar, de antemano muchas gracias!

Comment: Hola mimus. Me alegra que encontraras la respuesta, por favor, traduce la pregunta para que pueda ser de ayuda a otros usuarios también. Completa el [tour] para más información.

Comment: hecho muchas gracias por avisarme

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ya quedo!!!!!!!! lo solucione con

```
most_likely = df_predictions.sort_values('Probas', ascending=False).head(5)
```

en lugar de el nlargest =3